# Can foreign key reference to a table with composite(i.e combination of two columns) key?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

```
**Table 1**
BOOK(bookID,bookEdition,bookName)
```

where combination of (bookID,bookEdition) is used as key

```
**Table2**
SHELF(id,shelfCode,book)
```

now i want my column "book" in table2 to reference the composite key(bookID,bookEdition) in Table1.

Can any one may please guide me what is the correct way of doing this. Or may please correct me if my approach wrong

Or we cannot add foreign key constraint to tables with composite keys??

Comment: or in short can foreign key constraint can be added as mentioned above

Comment: What datatype is column `book` in Table2?  Foreign keys match the same number of columns in both tables.  In your model, how does `book` know which `bookId` and `bookEdition` it belongs to?

Comment: thats what my question is. . . data types are same and i want to add foregin key constraint, is it possible for above mentioned scenario??

Comment: If you want to FK from Table2 into Table1, replace the column `book` with `BookId` and `bookEdition` so the columns you want to FK with are in both tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a **compound primary key** (made up of mulitple columns), all your foreign keys also **must** use all columns of the PK to reference that table. So, foreign key constraints can only be added referencing to whole of the key, not to a part of key.

Either you add both `bookID` and `bookEdition` to the `SHELF` table (which to me makes more sense as `bookID` and `bookEdition` together can uniquely identify a book) or create a separate master table for Book (with key `bookID`) and reference that table in all your other tables.